# Safari font-color

Tags: css, fonts, safari

This renders ok in as of today latest versions of Fx, IE and Chrome but not in Safari. Why is that?

```
input#div-name {font-color: #666666;}
```

With Safari the font is #a9a9a9 and I have check all related CSS files for that hex..

EDIT: Blur in unknown javascript caused this.

Comment: Example page please. #666666 is a web safe color, it should be the same.  How are you getting the font color of #a9a9a9?

Comment: `font-color` is not a valid CSS property.

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious answer that `font-color` is not a recognized property in any browser. If your real code has `color` instead, then it also has something that overrides this setting.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to your caching in Safari.

If your old CSS is cached in Safari then it needs to be cleared so that the new CSS file will take effect.

Comment: Did a full reset of the browser, cleared all history, cookies etc. Still strange color "error".